# In Vue, what is the relationship of template, render, VNode?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

During development of a vue project, and got some doubt regarding `template` / `render` / `VNode`.

After reading the document https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html, and google search, still didn't understand it well.

---

### Code

**main.js:** *(partly)*

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App),
  router
})
```

**App.vue:**

```
<template>
  <div id="content">
    <!--    <img src="./assets/logo.png" alt="">-->
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {}
</script>
```

---

### Questions

- What is `h` from `h => h(App)` ?
- And what is the type of `h`'s return value?
- Does the template always compile to a `VNode` or a function that returns a `VNode`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What is `h` from `h => h(App)`

`render: h => h(App)` is shorthand for:

```
render: function (createElement) {
    return createElement(App);
}
```

where `h` is shorthand for the `createElement` argument; a function to compile the template into a VNode

https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack-simple/issues/29#issuecomment-312902539

---

> What is the type of `h`'s return value?

Since `h` is the `createElement` function,
`h` here returns a VNode

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#createElement-Arguments

---

> Does the template always compile to a VNode or a function that returns
> a VNode

You can do either, just depending on your implementation. If you use `Vue.compile`, then you can compile the template into a render function:

```
var res = Vue.compile('<div><span>{{ msg }}</span></div>')

new Vue({
  data: {
    msg: 'hello'
  },
  render: res.render,
  staticRenderFns: res.staticRenderFns
})
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-compile

If you use the `createElement` function, then you compile the template directly into a VNode.

Comment: So is the actual `createElement` (or `h`) function provided by `vue` or tools like `webpack`?

Comment: @EricWang it's a Vue function. A VNode is an "element" in Vue's Virtual DOM, which is what Vue uses to create the real HTML DOM that's rendered on the page.

Comment: Ok, I found the source code (v2.6.10) of function `createElement()` here: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/b7c2d9366cf731a1551286b8ac712e6e0905070e/dist/vue.js#L3344 , and function `_createElement()` here: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/b7c2d9366cf731a1551286b8ac712e6e0905070e/dist/vue.js#L3363

Answer (score 1):

It's arrow function - shorthand version (ES6 syntax)

Full function:

```
render: function (createElement) {
    return createElement(App)
}
```

So `h` is alias for `createElement`

See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html

Especially: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#The-Virtual-DOM

Answer (score 1):

1. `h` is an alias to the `createElement` function as explained at the end of this [paragraph](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#JSX).
2. `h`, or better said the `createElement` function returns a virtual node, or VNode, a Vue internal representation of a regular HTML element, like a `div`. You can find more details in the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#The-Virtual-DOM) too.
3. Templates compile to the same render functions you were talking about. [Here the details](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#Template-Compilation). So basically, templates are an high level abstraction to create low level VNodes.