# In Vue, what parameters does createElement() actually get?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, vuejs2

*(This is a further question after this one: [In Vue, what is the relationship of template, render, VNode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57220143))*

Found `createElement()`'s source code (from [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/b7c2d9366cf731a1551286b8ac712e6e0905070e/dist/vue.js#L3344)):

```
function createElement (
    context,
    tag,
    data,
    children,
    normalizationType,
    alwaysNormalize
) { ... }
```

---

### Code

**main.js:** *(partly)*

```
import App from './App.vue'

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App),
  router
})
```

**App.vue:**

```
<template>
  <div id="content">
    <!--    <img src="./assets/logo.png" alt="">-->
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {}
</script>
```

---

### Questions

- **A.** In `App.vue`, `export default {}` will return an empty object, is that correct?
- **B.** In `main.js`:

  - **B-1.** `import App from './App.vue'`, will bind `App` to the empty object, is that correct?
  - **B-2.** `render: h => h(App)`, if the answer to previous two questions were yes, then here `h` *(which is alias of vue's `createElement()` function)* will get a single parameter, for `context` with value as empty object, is that correct?
  - **B-3.** But, that doesn't make much sense, because the template are actually rendered in the browser in my test, it's not empty.
- **C.** So, in the code above, how many parameters are passed to `createElement()`, and what is the value of each of them?
- **D.** Which part did I misunderstand about `Vue` or `ES6` in above description?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Single-file components, i.e. `.vue` files, go through special processing by Vue Loader. See:

https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/#what-is-vue-loader

This will interfere in the `export`/`import` process so that everything works as expected.

So:

> In `App.vue`, `export default {}` will return an empty object, is that correct?

It would for a `.js` file. But for a `.vue` file it won't, not once it's been through Vue Loader.

Try console logging the value of `App` in `main.js` to see what actual gets imported. You should see a `render` function (compiled from your template) as well a few other little supporting pieces.

**Update**

To answer your follow-up question from the comments.

`createElement` just creates a VDOM node. It does not create the component instance for that node. Vue further processes the tree of VDOM nodes after they are returned from `render` and creates any child component instances it needs. It'll then call `render` on those components to generate the VDOM nodes that they need and so on until everything is rendered.

I've created a small example to try to illustrate this. It consists of a parent with two component children. Notice that the logging for creating and rendering the child components does not happen straight away when calling `createElement`. Instead it happens after the `render` function has returned.

```js
const child = {
  render (createElement) {
    console.log('rendering the child')
    return createElement('div', null, ['hello'])
  },
  
  created () {
    console.log('child is created')
  }
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  
  components: {
    child
  },
  
  created () {
    console.log('parent is created')
  },
  
  render (createElement) {
    console.log('rendering the parent')
    
    const children = [
      createElement('child'),
      createElement('child')
    ]
    
    const root = createElement('div', null, children)
    
    console.log('finished calling createElement')
    
    return root
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: After checking the printed `App`, looks like the `render` function on imported `App` will be called by `createElement()` to finally get the VNode created, but not sure is that so.

Comment: @EricWang It's unclear from your comment precisely which VNode you're referring to, but `createElement` does not call `render`. I've updated my answer with an example to try to illustrate what happens when.

Answer (score 2):

> In App.vue, export default {} will return an empty object, is that correct?

No, `.vue` files are [Single File Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html) that are compiled by [`vue-loader`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader).

> B. In main.js:
> B-1. import App from './App.vue', will bind App to the empty object, is that correct?

No, see above.

> B-2. render: h => h(App), if the answer to previous two questions were yes, then here h (which is alias of vue's createElement() function) will get a single parameter, for context with value as empty object, is that correct?

No. `App` is a component ready to be attached to a Vue Instance. `import App` is simply importing the compiled file as an ES6 module.

> C. So, in the code above, how many parameters are passed to createElement(), and what is the value of each of them?

If you `console.log(App)` you will see the compiled module (at minimum):

```
{
  render: function render() {}
  staticRenderFns: Array[0]
  _compiled: true
  beforeCreate: Array[2]
  __file: "/src/App.vue"
  beforeDestroy: Array[1]
  _Ctor: Object
}
```

> D. Which part did I misunderstand about Vue or ES6 in above description?

Both. Vue files are compiled to become Vue Instances. ES6 modules encapsulate all sorts of functionality, and expose this functionality to other JavaScript files, as libraries.